Proof of Theorem 5.8 (Banach, Mazur) on Banach space theory (Fabian et. al.)
I'm trying to understand the proof of Banach-Mazur theorem on the book Banach space theory of Fabian et. al.

I don't get how the extension of $\tilde{T}(x)$ to $T(x)$ works. I guess that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ mentioned in the proof are the ones you get when you express $r$ as a convex combination of $r_1$ and $r_2$. Now, I've been trying to proof that this $T(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to prove it when $r \in \Delta$.
The rest of the proof is clear (if my assumption that $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$ and $\alpha+\beta = 1$ is correct), but the well definition of the function is what doesn't make sense to me.

If it is not assumed that the scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are chosen so that $r$ is a convex combination of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$, then the function is not well-defined.
To illustrate this, note that what is being accomplished in this part of the proof is elements of $C(\Delta )$ are being extended to be defined as elements of $C([0,1])$. Define $f:\Delta \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(t) := 1$, so that $f\in C(\Delta )$, and set $r := 1/2$. Then $r_{1} = 1/3$ and $r_{2} = 2/3$. Note that $0\cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $1\cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $0\cdot f(1/3) + \frac{3}{4} \cdot f(2/3) = \frac{3}{4}$, while $1\cdot f(1/3) + \frac{1}{4}\cdot f(2/3) =\frac{5}{4}$. So if $\alpha , \beta \in\mathbb{R}$ are chosen such that $r = \alpha r_{1} + \beta r_{2}$, the value of $\alpha f(r_{1}) + \beta f(r_{2})$ is not independent of the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
So you do need the assumption that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are chosen such that $r$ is a convex combination of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$. This makes the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ unique, so that the extension is well-defined.
As for why the extension is continuous, let $f\in C(\Delta )$ and let $\tilde{f}:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be the extension of $f$ to $[0,1]$ from the process above. As $\tilde{f}$ is locally an affine function on $[0,1]\setminus\Delta$, $\tilde{f}$ is continuous on $[0,1]\setminus \Delta$.
It will now be shown that $\tilde{f}$ is left continuous on $\Delta$. Let $x_{0}\in \Delta\setminus\{0\}$. The first case is that for some $\delta \in (0, x_{0})$, the set $(x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}) \cap \Delta$ is empty. In that case, $(x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}) \subseteq [0,1] \setminus \Delta$. So $\tilde{f}$ is an affine function when restricted to $(x_{0} - \delta, x_{0}]$ and is consequently left continuous at $x_{0}$ in this case.
Otherwise, suppose that for all $\delta > 0$, $(x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}) \cap \Delta$ is not empty. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the continuity of $f$ at $x_{0}$, there exists some $\eta\in (0, x_{0})$ such that $x\in (x_{0} - \eta , x_{0}]$ implies $|f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon$. As $(x_{0} - \eta , x_{0}) \cap \Delta$ is not empty, there is some $\delta \in (0, \eta )$ such that $x_{0} - \delta \in \Delta$. Let $r\in (x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}]$. Define $r_{1} := \max \{p\in \Delta : p < x\}$ and $r_{2} := \min \{p\in \Delta : x < p\}$, and let $\alpha , \beta \in [0,1]$ such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $r = \alpha r_{1} + \beta r_{2}$. As $x_{0} - \delta \in \Delta$ and $x_{0} - \delta < r$, it follows that $r_{1}\in [x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}]$. And as $x_{0} \in \Delta$ and $r < x_{0}$, it follows that $r_{2} \in [x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}]$. Then as $[x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}] \subseteq (x_{0} - \eta , x_{0}]$ and as $|f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in (x_{0} - \eta, x_{0}]$,
$\begin{align*}
|\tilde{f}(r) - \tilde{f}(x_{0})| &= |(\alpha f(r_{1}) + \beta f(r_{2})) - (\alpha f(x_{0}) + \beta f(x_{0}))| \\
&= |\alpha (f(r_{1}) - f(x_{0})) + \beta (f(r_{2}) - f(x_{0}))| \\
&\leq \alpha |f(r_{1}) - f(x_{0})| + \beta |f(r_{2}) - f(x_{0})| \\
&< \alpha \varepsilon + \beta \varepsilon \\
&= \varepsilon .
\end{align*}$
Hence $|\tilde{f}(r) - \tilde{f}(x_{0})| < \varepsilon$. As this holds for all $r \in (x_{0} - \delta , x_{0}]$, this shows that $\tilde{f}$ is left continuous at $x_{0}$ in this case. Therefore $\tilde{f}$ is left continuous on $\Delta$.
Consider $g:\Delta \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $g(t) := f(1-t)$, which is well defined as $\Delta = \{1-t : t\in \Delta \}$. Moreover, $g\in C(\Delta )$. It can be shown that the extension of $g$ to $[0,1]$ is given by $\tilde{g}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\tilde{g}(t) := \tilde{f}(1-t)$. Then by applying the left continuity argument above to $\tilde{g}$ and noting that $\tilde{g}$ is left continuous on $\Delta$ if and only if $\tilde{f}$ is right continuous on $\Delta$, it follows that $\tilde{f}$ is right continuous on $\Delta$.
Combining all that has been done, it is concluded that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous.

But why is the extension continuous?

I added details as to why the extension is continuous.
